# Postgres SQL Function converted to Snowflake SQL with a For Loop included

Tags: postgresql, function, for-loop, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case

I'm having some difficulty converting a Postgres SQL function to Snowflake. I've done a few conversions so far, but this is my first one with a For Loop, which I'm not too familiar with as it is. I've only just started using Snowflake and I'm finding the documentation kind of sparse.

My biggest problem with this is getting the loop to work.

Here is the Postgres function that needs converting to snowflake -

```
create function mod_10_int(input character varying) returns integer
    language plpgsql
as
$$
DECLARE

    src_array char[];
    codepoints integer[];
    checksum integer = 0;
    i int = 1;
    ODD_FLAG INT = 1;

BEGIN

  -- Return NULL if either input isn't populated in SFDC
  CASE
    WHEN input IS NULL THEN RETURN NULL;
    ELSE

      src_array = string_to_array(input,NULL);

      --Convert source code to integer code points
      FOR i IN 1..(array_length(src_array,1)) LOOP
          CASE UPPER(src_array[i])
            WHEN '0' THEN codepoints[i] = 0;
            WHEN '1' THEN codepoints[i] = 1;
            WHEN '2' THEN codepoints[i] = 2;
            WHEN '3' THEN codepoints[i] = 3;
            WHEN '4' THEN codepoints[i] = 4;
            WHEN '5' THEN codepoints[i] = 5;
            WHEN '6' THEN codepoints[i] = 6;
            WHEN '7' THEN codepoints[i] = 7;
            WHEN '8' THEN codepoints[i] = 8;
            WHEN '9' THEN codepoints[i] = 9;
            WHEN 'A' THEN codepoints[i] = 0;
            WHEN 'B' THEN codepoints[i] = 1;
            WHEN 'C' THEN codepoints[i] = 2;
            WHEN 'D' THEN codepoints[i] = 3;
            WHEN 'E' THEN codepoints[i] = 4;
            WHEN 'F' THEN codepoints[i] = 5;
            WHEN 'G' THEN codepoints[i] = 6;
            WHEN 'H' THEN codepoints[i] = 7;
            WHEN 'I' THEN codepoints[i] = 8;
            WHEN 'J' THEN codepoints[i] = 9;
            WHEN 'K' THEN codepoints[i] = 0;
            WHEN 'L' THEN codepoints[i] = 1;
            WHEN 'M' THEN codepoints[i] = 2;
            WHEN 'N' THEN codepoints[i] = 3;
            WHEN 'O' THEN codepoints[i] = 4;
            WHEN 'P' THEN codepoints[i] = 5;
            WHEN 'Q' THEN codepoints[i] = 6;
            WHEN 'R' THEN codepoints[i] = 7;
            WHEN 'S' THEN codepoints[i] = 8;
            WHEN 'T' THEN codepoints[i] = 9;
            WHEN 'U' THEN codepoints[i] = 0;
            WHEN 'V' THEN codepoints[i] = 1;
            WHEN 'W' THEN codepoints[i] = 2;
            WHEN 'X' THEN codepoints[i] = 3;
            WHEN 'Y' THEN codepoints[i] = 4;
            WHEN 'Z' THEN codepoints[i] = 5;
            ELSE codepoints[i] = 0; ----Error case
          END CASE;
      END LOOP;

      --Mod 10 logic
      FOR i IN REVERSE (array_length(codepoints,1))..1 LOOP
        IF ODD_FLAG % 2 = 1
          THEN IF (2 * codepoints[i]) > 9
                 THEN checksum := checksum + (2 * codepoints[i]) - 9;
               ELSE checksum := checksum + (2 * codepoints[i]);
               END IF;
          ELSE checksum := checksum + codepoints[i];
        END IF;

        ODD_FLAG := ODD_FLAG + 1;

      END LOOP;


      --Conversion to string for formatting, and output
      RETURN (checksum * 9) % 10;

  END CASE;
END;
$$;
```

I'm trying to just get the Loop working without the usage of variables so far - this is what I have so far

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$  
      --Convert source code to integer code points
      --FOR i IN 1 to (array_length(src_array,1)) LOOP
   BEGIN     FOR i IN 1 to ARRAY_SIZE(TO_ARRAY('A')) DO
        SELECT  CASE 
            WHEN (TO_ARRAY(UPPER('A'))) = '0' THEN '0'
            WHEN (TO_ARRAY(UPPER('A'))) = '1' THEN '1'
            WHEN (TO_ARRAY(UPPER('A'))) = '2' THEN '2'
            WHEN (TO_ARRAY(UPPER('A'))) = '3' THEN '3'
            WHEN (TO_ARRAY(UPPER('A'))) = '4' THEN '4'
            WHEN (TO_ARRAY(UPPER('A'))) = '5' THEN '5'
            WHEN (TO_ARRAY(UPPER('A'))) = '6' THEN '6'
            WHEN (TO_ARRAY(UPPER('A'))) = '7' THEN '7'
            WHEN (TO_ARRAY(UPPER('A'))) = '8' THEN '8'
            WHEN (TO_ARRAY(UPPER('A'))) = '9' THEN  '9'
            WHEN (TO_ARRAY(UPPER('A'))) = 'A' THEN  '0'
            WHEN (TO_ARRAY(UPPER('A'))) = 'B' THEN  '1'
            WHEN (TO_ARRAY(UPPER('A'))) = 'C' THEN  '2'
            WHEN (TO_ARRAY(UPPER('A'))) = 'D' THEN  '3'
            WHEN (TO_ARRAY(UPPER('A'))) = 'E' THEN '4'
            WHEN (TO_ARRAY(UPPER('A'))) = 'F' THEN  '5'
            WHEN (TO_ARRAY(UPPER('A'))) = 'G' THEN  '6'
            WHEN (TO_ARRAY(UPPER('A'))) = 'H' THEN  '7'
            WHEN (TO_ARRAY(UPPER('A'))) = 'I' THEN  '8'
            WHEN (TO_ARRAY(UPPER('A'))) = 'J' THEN  '9'
            WHEN (TO_ARRAY(UPPER('A'))) = 'K' THEN  '0'
        
            ELSE '0'
            --ELSE codepoints[i] = 0; ----Error case
          END 
      END FOR;
      $$;
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this as a user defined function (UDF) that will be used as part of a SQL statement? Snowflake SQL UDFs do not have loops or flow control. They are SQL fragments. If you need looping or other flow control, you'll want to use JavaScript, Python, Java, or Scala to create a UDF.

Comment: Hi - thanks @GregPavlik - Yes the Postgres UDF that I'm converting is part of a larger SQL statement.  I didn't know that about no Loops in Snowflake SQL UDFs.  When you say use Javascript, etc to create the UDF, does that mean I can create the function still, I just need to specify language = javascript?

Comment: Maybe you don't even need a loop for this. Can you share some sample data and expected output?

Comment: @Cwnova, yes, this UDF does not seem to refer to table data so it can be expressed as a procedural code UDF (JavaScript, Python, Java, Scala). Dave shows a sample conversion to Python.

Comment: @Rajat The function calls a couple other functions but with those stripped down to their outputs - here is a sample 'select select mod_10_int('7010120K184BA125AC')' which returns 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting to Python and using Python conventions it could look like this (without sample data and expected outputs, it is hard to verify):

```
create or replace function mod_10_int (input varchar)
returns int
language python
runtime_version = '3.8'
handler = 'mod_10_int'
as
$$
def mod_10_int(input):
    codepoints = []
    checksum = 0
    ODD_FLAG = 1

    if not input:
        return None
    else:
        src_array = list(input)
        for character in src_array:
            if character >= '0' and character <= '9':
                codepoints.append(int(character))
            elif character.upper() >= 'A' and character.upper() <= 'Z':
                codepoints.append((ord(character)-65) % 10)
            else:
                codepoints.append(0)

        # Mod 10 logic
        codepoints.reverse()
        for i in codepoints:
            if ODD_FLAG % 2 == 1:
                if (2 * i) > 9:
                    checksum += (2 * i) - 9
                else:
                    checksum += 2 * i
            else:
                checksum += i

            ODD_FLAG += 1

    return (checksum * 9) % 10
$$;
```

Comment: Dave - this looks good. I actually cut my original function a bit short in the case statement, it goes through the letters of the alphabet all the way to the end and reuses numbers after hitting 0. So A= 0, B=2,....K=0, L = 1,.... U=0, ......Z=5

The function in postgres calls a couple other functions but stripping those out for what they return - here is a sample call 
select mod_10_int('7010120K184BA125AC') = 4

using your provided solution gives a return of 6, although I suspect that might be do to how the letters are being used in your original proposed solution

Comment: So I would probably change this to if character >= 'A' and character <= 'Z' if the pattern is the same. Some similar small tweaks should get you there.

Comment: Yes the pattern is the same, just cycling through the alphabet and assigning numbers, starting at 0-9 and then restarting until hitting Z

Comment: I corrected the function above to handle A-Z and to wrap around 0-9 for outputs using the % modulo operator. Now it gives Z = 5

Comment: This is working as far as returning an Int but not matching up to my results in Postgres - 
SELECT mod_10_int('7010120K184BA125AC')   = 4
SELECT mod_10_int('2010120K184BA125AD')  = 7

In snowflake, the first statement returns 7, and the second one is returning 6

Comment: Oops, had an indentation but on ODD_FLAG += 1 which left it outside the for loop. After correcting that, it now gives mod_10_int('7010120K184BA125AC') = 4

Comment: Badass - that checks out. Thank you so much Dave, that would have taken me an incredibly long time to figure out